# How can I output the literal contents of a String in Java?

Tags: java, string

In Java, how can I print out the literal contents of a String? For example:

```
String s="Hello \"world\"";
System.out.println(s);
```

would print:

```
Hello "world"
```

How can I get it to print this?

```
Hello \"world\"
```

Comment: Those *are* the literal contents of the string. The backslashes are only there to tell the compiler that the quotation mark isn't marking the end of the string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Blender pointed out in a comment, what you get with `println` really IS the literal contents of the String.  However, if you want to get the text that you have to insert in quotation marks in a Java program, then what you can do is to use the `escapeJava` method of the Apache `StringEscapeUtils` class.   See http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJava(java.lang.String)

```
String s = "Hello \"world\"";
String escaped = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(s); 
System.out.println(escaped);
```

Comment: Try it with `"привет"`.

Answer (score 0):

Some programming languages have such a literal mode (like Groovy: `"""Verbatim mode"""`), but Java does not.

If you want to get Java to print `Hello \"world\"`, you have to escape it properly in the .java file:
`s= "Hello \\\"world\\\""`. The first `\\ -> \` and the second `\" -> "` in the final String.

Sadly that's a common pain when working with regular expressions, which involve a lot of `\` in the strings.